# button onclick opening a wordpress shortcode

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onclick, shortcode

Im trying to make a button opening a shortcode from the ultimate shortcode plugin.
Here is my example:

```
<button id="showInfo" onclick="showInfo()">Video</button>
```

javascript:

```
var infoSC = '[su_lightbox_content id="showInfo"]Inline content[/su_lightbox_content]';

function showInfoSC(){
  return infoSC;
}
```

I want to open  a ligtbox based on the content of a post (advanced custom fields)

```
<?php the_field('info'); ?>
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. What are you expecting to happen when you click that button? A pop-up, modal? Also in order to run the shortcode you need a php function `do_shortcode('[shortcode_here]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to utilize the `do_shortcode()` function in wordpress to get the actual output that a shortcode will return.

```
do_shortcode('[su_lightbox_content id="showInfo"]Inline content[/su_lightbox_content]');
```

This will return the string of whatever the shortcode outputs. Keep in mind that javascript will break using a multi-line string, so be mindful of the html code that the shortcode will output if you plan to store it in a string in javascript.

My recommendation would be to have whatever that shortcode shows hidden via CSS, then utilize javascript to make the content visible.

For example, say the shortcode outputs

```
<div class="su_lightbox_content" id="showInfo">
  Inline content
</div>
```

In your CSS, just add

```
#showInfo {
  display: none;
}
```

And your javascript function:

```
function showInfo() {
  document.getElementById("showInfo").style.display = "block";
}
```

This way, you can include the shortcode in the post/page normally and avoid any complications with using javascript to create a new element from a raw html string.